# How to move a sprite to your fingers position when using the isTouched() method LibGDX

Tags: android, libgdx, touch

Im currently using the Desktop Launcher and this code for movement

```
if(Gdx.input.isKeyPressed(Keys.A)){
            position.x -= speed;
            movement = "left";
        }       

        else if(Gdx.input.isKeyPressed(Keys.D)){
            position.x += speed;
            movement = "right";     
        }
```

What i want to do is move left when my fingers on the left of the sprite, and right when its on the right

Any ideas ?

I havent used the isTouched method as of yet, only with Actors(TextButton)

Many Thanks

Answer (score 1):

```
@Override
public boolean touchDown(int screenX, int screenY, int pointer, int button) {
    if(button == Buttons.LEFT){
        posX = screenX - sprite.getWidth()/2;
        posY = Gdx.graphics.getHeight() - screenY - sprite.getHeight()/2;
    }
    if(button == Buttons.RIGHT){
        posX = Gdx.graphics.getWidth()/2 - sprite.getWidth()/2;
        posY = Gdx.graphics.getHeight()/2 - sprite.getHeight()/2;
    }
    return false;
}
```

Check this tutorial it gives plenty of info and explanations: http://www.gamefromscratch.com/post/2013/10/15/LibGDX-Tutorial-4-Handling-the-mouse-and-keyboard.aspx
PEACE!

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend checking out https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/wiki/A-simple-game

This is very basic and simple game tutorial where the user moves a bucket where the finger is positioned, to move when you click right of the sprite simply add a condition that if where you are clicking is greater than the sprite center (spritewidth/2) then go right, if its less then go left.